# How to check if Firestore document creation didn't work?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have this java method that creates a document in Firestore:

```
private void createNewDocument(CollectionReference usersRef, String deviceId, SharedPreferences prefs) {
    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("timeStamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

    usersRef.document(deviceId).set(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Document successfully created");
            })

            //I need all cases other than success. The bottom two don't work all the time
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Not successful");
                    creationFailed(prefs);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                creationFailed(prefs);
            });

}
```

So I turned off the internet to test what the app would do when `createNewDocument()` is called without internet access, and to my frustration neither `addOnCompleteListener()` nor `addOnFailureListener()` were called. I need to know when ANYTHING other than a successful document creation happens. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is that the `Firestore` database works by default with persistance enabled on native apps. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#java). The `addOnSuccessListener` only gets called when the data is saved to the server.

That means that you don't even need to check if you saved the data or not. As you see the code is not even asynchornous. The Firebase SDK will sync the data to the Firestore database as soon it gains connection.

You can either disable the `persistance` with::

```java
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

I would not recommend that.

Or use the `onSnapshotListener` and configure it to listen to local changes as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).:

```java
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        String source = snapshot != null && snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
                ? "Local" : "Server";

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, source + " data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, source + " data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

In most cases it's enough to rely on the Firebase SDK to save the data when the device regains connection. That is what I would recommen. Continue with your code as if it is saved. If that is possible by the bussinies logic.

Comment: So if there's no internet then the document and database will be created on the user's device as if it's a SharedPreference? Meaning if the user remains offline all the time can my app always read documents from his device?

Comment: Also just to be clear, the answer to the original question is that this `if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) { Log.d(TAG, source + " data: " + snapshot.getData()); }` will always work when document creation is unsuccessful for ANY reason?

Comment: Yes the documents will be created on the users device. And even if the user is offline he can read the data he has already listened to before. He ofcourse can't get new data from the databas while offline but the data he already had is awailable.

Comment: And answer to the second comment. Yes. The listeners will be invoked immediately after you change data even if the user is offline.